# Is repeated factorial anova (3 x 3) the right way to answer my research question?

Tags: database-design, anova, factorial

I'm currently developing an online experiment where people will be rating their sense of duty after reading a vignette. However in order to minimise the amount of time spent for each participant I amalgamated two aspects into each vignette.

Context of illness - A, B, C
Context of scenario - X, Y, Z

Outcome is a likert rating from 1 to 7

There are in total 9 permutations which I've split into three groups therefore meaning each combination should be viewed equally across the entire population sample. However if I want to measure the impact of context of illness and context of scenario separately can this be done using a repeated measured factorial anova? Each person will be exposed to A,B,C,X,Y,Z however the order that they are combined will be different (as they are split into the three groups)so for example group 1 has combination of A + X, B+ Y, C+Z, and group 2 has combinations B+X, C+Y and A+Z, and group 3 has combinations C+X, A+Y and B+Z

I am typically more familiar with regression analyses and feel like a fish out of water here.

I've found examples of 3x3 factorial analysis but struggling to find 3 x 3 repeated factorial analysis. I understand in some ways what i've done is created a repeated design but also between group design as not all permutations are viewed by each person.

I am still developing this study and open to alternative methods of presenting the vignettes to participants.